# How to change page size in pdf generated by pisa

Tags: python, django, pisa

I am creating pdf from my html page using pisa in django framework. Can anyone please tell me how to adjust the pdf page size. I tried to use A5 but its not reflecting. Please find the code below:

```
       context_dict = {
            'pagesize':'A5',
            'result_detail': obj.result_object(slug, roll_no),
            'roll_no': roll_no
       }
       template = get_template('widgets/result.html')
       context = Context(context_dict)
       html  = template.render(context)
       result = StringIO.StringIO()
       pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by overloading a default CSS definition.
To get the current default CSS use the command line tool like this:

```
xhtml2pdf --css-dump > /path-to-your-project/default.css
```

Then, open the resulting file and insert the following line at the end:

```
@page { size: A5 }
```

In your code, you can use the resulting file as follows:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result,  default_css=open('default.css','r').read())
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply writing the snippet below in the style tag, did the trick for me.

```
@page { size: A5 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).